# smtp doesn't work in c# -but its ok with python

Tags: python, c#, smtp, smtpclient

I have a problem with SMTP programming in C# in my project. It does not work in C# but it's ok with Python.

I have both codes here. What do I need to change in the C# program to make it work properly?

This is the SMTP server from our university:

---

**Python code**

```py
def send_mail():
    port = 443  # For SSL
    smtp_server = "smtps.****.be"
    sender_email = "***********"  # Enter your address
    receiver_email = "***********"  # Enter receiver address

    # create message object instance
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    message = "Hello"

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From'] = '**********'
    msg['To'] =  '*********'
    msg['Subject'] = "Test"

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    username = '********'
    password = '********'
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(
            sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string()
        )

    print("successfully sent email to {}".format(msg['To']))
```

---

**C# code**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtps.******.be");
mail.From = new MailAddress("***********");
mail.To.Add(textBox1.Text);

mail.Subject = "reminder ";
mail.Body = textBox4.Text;

SmtpServer.Port = 443;
//username 
//password 
SmtpServer.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("*****","*******");

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indent the C# code consistently. It's kind of hard to read and understand now.

Comment: Is it throwing any exception? If yes what is that ?

Comment: @MichałT But why? The [`constructor`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs#L90) sets the `port` field, as does the [`Port`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs#L233) property, so I don't see that it would make a difference.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed, but the built-in SmtpClient, didn't use to support implicit SSL. You can try setting `EnableSsl = true`, though you might need to look at a more modern client such as that provided by the MailKit package.

Comment: The port isn't set as 25, it's set as 443. It's being set here: `SmtpServer.Port = 443;`. That ends up setting the same field as the constructor does, so your suggested change doesn't improve things.